# Firebase Dynamic link API returning unexpected result

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase API to generate short link:

[https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=XYZ](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links)

It work most of time and generated expected result like `https:// abc123.app.goo.gl/WXYZ` but randomly it sometime generated `https:// goo.gl/xyz` sort of link. And finally when this executed by client it does not contain expected parsed result.

I have no idea why this is happening. Any one suggestion what's wrong going here.

Comment: can you post an example of the body you are sending along with the request? Are you using longLink or json parameters method?

Comment: I think Firebase has a glitch.Maybe you should contact the Firebase staff.

Comment: I'm but no solution till now.