# How to display site name in Firebase Deeplink redirect link to web

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on integration of Firebase Dynamic link implementation support for iOS platform. I got some issue I have added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42484750/2624806), but no clue till now.

Other then I observer, it showing url **goo.gl** at top-right.

How to do that?? Any suggestion what param I should choose([firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links)) to display my site name instead goo.gl.

[image]

In one of question sample mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603748/2624806), it showing site name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'param' you can use to change that URL — it is the domain of the Universal Link. If you want to change what is displayed there, you need to change the domain you're using.

However, Firebase Dynamic Links do not currently support white labelled link domains so there is no way you can do this. You'll need to implement your own Universal Links system, or use [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), which offers all the features of Dynamic Links in addition to domain white labelling.